# how to convert seconds in min:sec format

Tags: c#, time

how to convert seconds in Minute:Second format

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
int totalSeconds = 222;
int seconds = totalSeconds % 60;
int minutes = totalSeconds / 60;
string time = minutes + ":" + seconds;
```

Comment: That would format 125 seconds as "2:5" whereas I *suspect* 2:05 would be more appropriate.

Comment: Yeah, the string is not formated to give the seconds a leading zero for single digit numbers, so I would do it like so: string time = (totalSeconds / 60).ToString() + ":" + (totalSeconds % 60).ToString("00");

Answer (score 45):

A versatile version is to use `TimeSpan` like this:

```
var span = new TimeSpan(0, 0, seconds); //Or TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds); (see Jakob C´s answer)
var yourStr = string.Format("{0}:{1:00}", 
                            (int)span.TotalMinutes, 
                            span.Seconds);
```

Answer (score 23):

Just for completeness I will add an answer using `TimeSpan` (works as of .NET 4.0):

```
int seconds = 1045;
var timespan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds);            
Console.WriteLine(timespan.ToString(@"mm\:ss"));
```

Comment: +1 for `.FromSeconds` instead of using constructor like me. But your code does not compile - no overload of `.ToString`.

Comment: AFAIK, this overload was added in .NET 4: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992632.aspx

Comment: Ahh fair :) But another problem is that it will only show up to 59 minutes. However, I don't know whether that will be enough for Ramesh.

Comment: Good point.  Seeing what answer was actually chosen by Ramesh I really don't think he cares that much about the format though :-)

Answer (score 6):

Something like this:

```
string minSec = string.Format("{0}:{1:00}", seconds / 60, seconds % 60);
```

Note that that will ensure the seconds are always displayed as two digits, e.g. "2:05" for 125 seconds. The minutes aren't currently treated the same way, but of course they could be.

This doesn't deal well with negative numbers. If your seconds may be negative, you may want something like this:

```
string minSec = string.Format("{0}:{1:00}", seconds / 60, 
                              (Math.Abs(seconds)) % 60);
```

Finally, will you always have less than an hour of seconds? It might look odd to see "80:00" when you really mean "1:20:00" for example.

Answer (score 5):

```
double seconds=125;    
TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds).ToString()
```

will give you : `00:02:05`. As per my understanding this built-in solution is more extensible, since it can give you hours too, without any plumbing of the logic.

Comment: Ten years after: this adds milliseconds to the resulting string, which is not what the OP asked for.

Comment: Ten years after : You can use `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss")` to get in hours, min, sec format. If you want mSec as well, you can use `.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss\:fff");`

Answer (score 4):

```
var seconds = 60;
//10,000 ticks in a millisecond
var ticks = seconds*10000*1000;
DateTime dt = new DateTime(ticks);
dt.ToString("mm:ss");
```

Comment: does it still work when there would be hours? eg. 3700sec are 1h 1min 40sec. Wouldn't it return 1:40 instead of 61:40?

Comment: Yes it'll work with hours, days and every member of the DateTime struct. Try it yourself ;)

Comment: Adding some explanation along with the code would make this answer better.

Answer (score 3):

Simple maths. 60 seconds to a minute.

```
int mins = totalseconds/60;
int secs = totalseconds % 60;

Console.Writeline(string.Format("{0}:{1}", mins, secs));
```

Answer (score 3):

Not strictly answering the original question, but in case anyone (or myself) in the future comes here from google wanting to format a float with milliseconds as well:

```
float secs = 23.69;
string m_ss_mmm = string.Format("{0}:{1:00}.{2:000}", (int)secs / 60, (int)(secs % 60), (secs - ((int)secs)) * 1000);
```

Result:

```
0:23.690
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative way to display the seconds as e.g. "2:05" could be to use PadLeft.

```
string time = minutes.ToString() + ":" + seconds.ToString().PadLeft(2,'0');
```

Answer (score 0):

What works for me...

```
public static string SecondsToMinutes(int seconds)
{
   var ts = new TimeSpan(0, 0, seconds);                
   return new DateTime(ts.Ticks).ToString(seconds >= 3600 ? "hh:mm:ss" : "mm:ss");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need it as float or double:

```
float seconds = 339;
float totalTimeInMins = (float) (Math.Floor(seconds / 60) + (seconds % 60) / 100);
```