# How to convert every format to seconds in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, data-conversion

My application is in C#, im trying to create a method that will convert the passed value to seconds (Time), the format that will be coming is not fixed,  that be be provided by the user hence it will be dynamic. It can be **hh:mm or mm:ss or hh:mm:ss**, it can be any valid time format. The value that i will be getting from a certain file will always be a time part. The formats will be passed by the user depending on the condition / requirement. It can be any valid time format.

**I have tried**

1. Using Timespan.Parse but it dont accept the format.
2. Using Timespan.ParseExact but my compiler is giving error that timespan dont contains the definition ParseExact.

Other option that i have add the logic for  conversion to seconds depending on the format,also I dont want to add condition for every format and  then use parse method. Is there any other generic way to achieve the same? such that i can pass the value and format and it should convert to seconds. Other things that i have tried are far away from being generic and specifically focus on any one format like the one in the link below

[how to convert seconds in min:sec format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665012/how-to-convert-seconds-in-minsec-format)

Comment: How would you differentiate between hh:mm and mm:ss? This is the main reason I think a nice generic example is going to be incredibly difficult to come up with

Comment: @CallumBradbury yes, its difficult to identify without writing any additional logic, that's what i wanted to ask, if its possible to achieve without writing long lines of code.

Comment: Imagine you have `10:20` as input. Is it *10 hours 20 minutes* or *10 minutes 20 seconds*? Ambiguity makes you task (in general case) impossible to implement.

Comment: *No* amount of additional logic will help you read the mind of the user

Comment: Are you saying the user will provide a value AND the format or just the value?

Comment: @DoctorMick yes the value and format both will be available. We have format available as well but depending on requirement the user may pass any valid time format, maybe sometime hh:mm or mm:ss ir hh:mm:ss

Comment: this is wat im looking for if possible
var converted_Seconds=ConversionMethod(myValue, myformat);
Is there any method or  any source available to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know whether this is the best possible solution or whether i made it more complex while posting the question. Below is what i have implemented and its satisfying my requirement

After getting the value in the double format like this "01:30" im converting it to Datetime object

```
var DateObj= Convert.ToDateTime("MyValue");
DateObj.ToString("MyFormat");
var TempVariable=DateObj.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds;
```

If there are any short comings with this solution please comment or improve my answer

Answer (score 0):

Well, *ambiguity* makes the problem unable to be implemented in *general case*, e.g. have a look at

```
  10:20
```

is it *10 hours and 20 minutes* and so the answer is `10 * 3600 + 20 * 60 == 37200` or just *10 minutes and 20 seconds* which equals to `10 * 60 + 20 = 620` seconds. However, if you know how to treat this ambiguity, you can use `TryParseExact`:

```
  private static double InSeconds(string value, params string[] formats) {
    // if no formats provided, use default ones:
    // try these formats in this particular order:
    if ((null == formats) || (formats.Length <= 0))
      formats = new string[] { 
        @"h\:m\:s", 
        @"h\:m", 
        @"m\:s" }
    else
      // In case of unescaped formats like "h:m" (see comments below)
      // we automatically escape them
      for (int i = 0; i < formats.Length; ++i)
        if (formats[i] != null)
          formats[i] = Regex.Replace(formats[i], 
            @"(?<!\\)[^A-Za-z\\]", 
            match => @"\" + match.Value);

    TimeSpan result; 

    if (TimeSpan.TryParseExact(value, formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out result))
      return result.TotalSeconds;
    else
      return double.NaN;  
  }
```

Test

```
  // 23 hours 53 minutes == 85980 seconds
  // Please, notice ambiguity: 23 minutes 53 seconds is also possible
  // however the routine states that h:m should be tried first  
  Console.Write(InSeconds("23:53"));
  // 47 minutes 53 seconds == 2873 seconds:
  // hour:minutes tried first, fails and minutes:seconds succeeds  
  Console.Write(InSeconds("47:53")); 
  // 99:99 == NaN
  // All three expected formats fail on such an input
  Console.Write(InSeconds("99:99")); 

  // Custom format - 45240
  Console.Write(InSeconds("12:34", @"hh\:mm")); 
  // Custom format - NAN: hh requires leading zeros (i.e. 01:34)
  Console.Write(InSeconds("1:34", @"hh\:mm")); 
  // Custom formats: 1 day 12 hours 34  minutes - 131640
  Console.Write(InSeconds("1.12:34", @"hh\:mm", @"d\.hh\:mm")); 

  // Custom format (unescaped, notice abscence of \) - 45240
  Console.Write(InSeconds("12:34", @"hh:mm"));
```

Comment: i have tried using TryParse.Exact but during compile time only im getting the error as "System.Timespan  does not contain the definition for TryParse.Exact".

Comment: @Sam Sam: please notice, `TimeSpan.TryParseExact` (no dot between `TryParse` and `Exact`)

Comment: are those time format are supported that are mentioned in the answer, or more are supported, also are the formats to be passed in the same manner? as i passed the format "hh:mm" and it did not returned any result.

Comment: yes it is framework issue i think, my solution is in Framework 3.5 which dont support the method  TryParseExact. Im checking this on sample application with framework 4.5

Comment: @Sam Sam: you have a wrong format string, probably, it should be `@"hh\:mm"`i.e. `hours:minutes` with mandatory leading zeros; see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287(v=vs.110).aspx fro details

Comment: @Sam Sam: when you have a *restriction* (.Net 3.5 in your case), please mention it in the question (usually as tag in addtion to C#, datetime and data conversion)

Comment: @Dmitrry Bychenko can i pass my formats rather than using the string array or format, i have tried passing but its not converting

Comment: this is the method i have created private static double InSeconds(string value, string Format), and this is what im doing in processing if (TimeSpan.TryParseExact(value, formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out result))
                    return result.TotalSeconds; and the value im passing in format is @"hh\:mm" still the conversion is not happening

Comment: @Sam Sam: sure, you can pass your own formats (see my edit)

Comment: @Sam Sam: `@"hh\:mm"` wants *leading zeros*, e.g. `"1.23"` will fail to convert, since `"01.23"` (notice zero) is expected. Try using `@"h\:m"` format string which is more lienient

Comment: one final thing, im getting the formats in a certain file and the formats that are coming are like this "hh:mm" or "mm:ss" or "hh:mm:ss" what can i do for this, it is not converting with these kinda formats

Comment: @Sam Sam: then modify the formats given: `format = Regex.Replace(format, @"[^A-Za-z]", match => @"\" + match.Value);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
    class TimeParser
    {
        Regex tripleReg = new Regex(@"([\d]{1,2}):([\d]{1,2}):([\d]{1,2})");
        Regex doubleReg = new Regex(@"([\d]{1,2}):([\d]{1,2})");

        public enum Format
        {
            HoursMinutesSeconds,
            HoursMinutes,
            MinutesSeconds
        }

        public TimeSpan Parse(string data)
        {
            if (tripleReg.IsMatch(data))
                return Parse(data, Format.HoursMinutesSeconds);
            else
            {
                var match = doubleReg.Match(data);

                var segment = match.Groups[1];
                var value = int.Parse(segment.Value);

                if (value < 60)
                    return Parse(data, Format.MinutesSeconds);
                else
                    return Parse(data, Format.HoursMinutes);
            }
        }

        public TimeSpan Parse(string data, Format format)
        {
            TimeSpan result;
            Match match;

            var hours = 0;
            var minutes = 0;
            var seconds = 0;

            switch (format)
            {
                case Format.HoursMinutesSeconds:
                    match = tripleReg.Match(data);
                    if (match.Success)
                    {
                        int.TryParse(match.Groups[1].Value, out hours);
                        int.TryParse(match.Groups[2].Value, out minutes);
                        int.TryParse(match.Groups[3].Value, out seconds);
                    }
                    break;
                case Format.HoursMinutes:
                    match = doubleReg.Match(data);
                    if (match.Success)
                    {
                        int.TryParse(match.Groups[1].Value, out hours);
                        int.TryParse(match.Groups[2].Value, out minutes);
                    }
                    break;
                case Format.MinutesSeconds:
                    match = doubleReg.Match(data);
                    if (match.Success)
                    {
                        int.TryParse(match.Groups[1].Value, out minutes);
                        int.TryParse(match.Groups[2].Value, out seconds);
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            result = new TimeSpan(hours, minutes, seconds);

            return result;
        }
    }
```

Tests:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var parser = new TimeParser();

        Console.WriteLine(parser.Parse("60:34").TotalSeconds); //218040 seconds, hh:mm

        Console.WriteLine(parser.Parse("55:10").TotalSeconds); //3310 seconds, mm:ss

        Console.WriteLine(parser.Parse("3:33:34").TotalSeconds); //12814 seconds, hh:mm:ss

        Console.WriteLine(parser.Parse("12:34", TimeParser.Format.HoursMinutes).TotalSeconds); //45240 seconds

        Console.WriteLine(parser.Parse("55:10", TimeParser.Format.MinutesSeconds).TotalSeconds); //3310 seconds

        Console.WriteLine(parser.Parse("3:33:34", TimeParser.Format.HoursMinutesSeconds).TotalSeconds); //12814 seconds

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```