# How do you convert mins to hour:min in C#?

Tags: c#

So I am getting output in #s and I need to convert this to hour:min form.

For example, 50 mins = 00:50  and 100 mins would be 01:40.

How do I accomplish this?

```
lbltime.Text = ??.ToString();
```

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665012/how-to-convert-seconds-in-minsec-format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Example

if you means the 50 mins is a parameter int mins = 50;

then:

```
int mins = 50;
lbltime.Text =  (mins / 60).ToString().PadLeft(2,'0') + ":" + (mins - ((int)(mins / 60)) * 60).ToString().PadLeft(2, '0');
```

Comment: `mins % 60` (modulo) is the normal way to do the minute part

Comment: Tanks Charlieface, your answer is more brevity.